# During testing, how can I fake MailerPlugin.send so I can get the sent email?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, stub, playframework-2.3

During testing I wish to fake play.api.libs.mailer.MailerPlugin in Play 2.3, so that I can get hold of the email being sent. How do I do this?

## App Code

```
package services
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import play.api.Play.current

object EmailService {
  def sendUserNotification(to: String, subject: String, content: String): Unit = {
    val email = Email(
      "subject",
      "Admin <admin@test.com>",
      Seq(to),
      bodyHtml = Some(s"""<html>
      | <body>
      |   $content
      | </body>
      | </html>
      | """.stripMargin)
    )
    // Should like to fake this from tests, but how?
    MailerPlugin.send(email)
  }
}
```

## Test Code

```
object Test {
  def testEmail(): Unit = {
    // How do I get hold of the sent email?
    EmailService.sendUserNotification("user@user.com", "Test", "Testing...")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options:

The easiest and maybe the best one: separate functions from side effect, separate the creation logic into a separate method and write a test for that, you can then call that from the side effecting `sendUserNotification`

```
def createUserNotification(...): Email = ...

def sendUserNotification(...): Unit = 
  MailerPlugin.send(createUserNotification(...))
```

If you have written lots of controllers etc which use your service already and you want to write tests that check if those send emails there is a set of plugins class names to disable and a set of plugins class names to enable on `FakeApplication` from the play test utils, so you could provide a fake implementation of `EmailPlugin` in your tests which just gathers up sent emails. `play.api.test.WithApplication` accepts a `FakeApplication` to its constructor that will be used when running the tests.

You could dependency inject the actual mail operation, by making the email plugin something that you inject where it is used, either as a constructor parameter or as an abstract method or value or even a function that you pass to your send method. For example:

```
sendUserNotification(...)(send: Email => Unit)
```

or

```
trait EmailService {
  def actuallySend(email: Email): Unit
}

object Emails extends EmailService {
  def actuallySend(email: Email) = MailerPlugin.send(email)
}
```

Comment: You mean fake `MailerPlugin` don't you? I ended up injecting a fake `MailerPlugin` anyway into `FakeApplication` through the technique you mention. This is what I wanted, since I avoid stubbing in tests as much as possible, due to the brittleness it brings with it.

Comment: Exactly what I meant! :)